# ASP.Net Site Configuration Tool

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, configuration, asp.net-membership

When I create a user account using the ASP Create User Wizard, the site administration tool reflects that the user exists but when I look in the ASP User and Membership tables in my database there are no users. When I used the ASP Reg SQL tool it was to configure a server database which I since moved to be a local database, which may perhaps be the problem. I am trying to link a Customer table to the ASP User table by way of the UserId guid, but right now there is nothing to return. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the membership provider connection string?

Comment: If you are not seeing the records in the database, you are likely looking at the wrong database.  Look at the connection string to ensure that it is pointing to the database that you THINK it's looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the sections below in your web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MySqlServer;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
...
  <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
        name="SqlProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
        connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
        applicationName="MyApplication"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true"
        passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

This will tell you what database it is using for your membership stuff.  You will want to look at the `connectionStingName` in the membership section (in this case MySqlConnection) and then look at the corresponding connection string to see if it is going where you expect it to.

Comment: This is the correct config section but NOT the correct setup for a db-integrated membership setup.

Comment: Correct this is for AD.  I Believe my comments still apply, correct?

Comment: I am concerned for you if you are using the domain administrator account to authenticate your membership provider.

Comment: Updated.  Both examples were taken directly from MSDN.  Be concerned for them.